# cmd_vel or commands/velocity?

Tags: navigation, move-base, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use the existing amcl/gmapping and create my own wheel motor drive actuator. it seems that the output from navigation (amcl/gmapping) are fed into move_base
http://wiki.ros.org/move_base

the above wiki shows that move_base dumps the velocity commands to /cmd_vel

but on the turtlebot simulator, I see the commands finally go to  ***/commands/velocity, in fact the /cmd_vel topic doesn't exist at all.

so which one is it really?  I just need to know the correct place for my actuator to get its commands from.

also gmapping does SLAM so supposedly it can also do localization, what is the reason we use a separate navigation package (amcl) ?

thanks
Yang

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222950/cmd_vel-or-commands/velocity?/) by [teddyyyy123](https://answers.ros.org/users/25214/teddyyyy123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-12-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2015-12-22**:
please, create another question about your gmapping and amcl doubts, as it relates to a different subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not familiar with the turtlebot simulator, but what matters is the type of your topic.
Velocity messages, as the `/cmd_vel`  produced by move_base have the type [Twist](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Twist.html) .

So, as long as you have the same topic type, you can always rename the topic to match the one expected by your subscriber, using the [remap](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/remap) command.

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2015-12-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0